# repeated measures regression

Tags: regression, repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis, panel-data

I was hoping that I could get some feedback in terms of keywords I should searching for, or concepts I need to consider with the following:

I have non-experimental data that I would like to model in a regression format.  Unfortunately, I only have 12 subjects and a set of repeated measures of 6 observations: spring, summer, fall for 2 years.  My question is what type of model should I consider to do this?  I absolutely have some reading to do, so I am hoping for any leads on where to start.. key words, or direct advice on a literature source.

Comment: What question are you trying to answer and what data have you collected? This question is too vague to get any useful information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your situation could be found referred to by various names including: [panel data analysis](http://www.nyu.edu/its/pubs/connect/fall03/yaffee_primer.html) ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panel_data))--most common name in social sciences, longitudinal data analysis--most common name in biomedical sciences; names for the models include: [multilevel models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilevel_model), and hierarchical linear models.  Probably the best regarded intro book would be [Fitzmaurice, Laird & Ware](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470380276).

Answer (score 3):

Two general areas are multilevel models and generalized estimating equations. You could also search on "longitudinal data"
There are many good books on this subject. One that I like is [Hedeker and Gibbons](http://books.google.com/books/about/Longitudinal_Data_Analysis.html?id=TRwucwebYMcC), but choice of book partly depends on what software you are using and how technical a book you want.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I mainly use R, and the level of technicality shouldn't be too much of a problem (I've had 2 theory courses, but we never touched on these types of things, nor in my applied classes).  I will check out your suggestions.. thanks again.